# Framerate "hitches" every 5 seconds in fullscreen games and compositors

Tags: x11, manjaro, amd-graphics

I'm running Manjaro GNOME 18.1.4 with the Xfce desktop environment, using amdgpu (xf86-video-amdgpu  19.1.0-1).

If I run a game in fullscreen with Vsync enabled, and when Xfwm4's composer is disabled, I get small "hitches" every 5 seconds where the screen freezes for a fraction of a second, but **only** when the game is running in fullscreen. This is how it looks in Gallium HUD with Quakespasm running with Vsync enabled:

[image: Screenshot of Gallium HUD graph, showing dips in the framerate every five seconds]

When I enable compositing in Xfwm4, the graph shows this, but the "hitches" remain:

[image: Screenshot of Gallium HUD graph, showing the framerate hovering around 60 fps]

If I run glxgears in windowed mode while compositing is enabled, it's affected by the "hitches" too but the graph doesn't show this.

It's not a fault of Quakespasm as this also happens in `glxgears` and Retroarch.

Running `xrandr --verbose` shows this for the currently used screen. Note that the refresh rate is 60.02Hz:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x59) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
    Identifier: 0x55
    Timestamp:  3131421
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3 4 5
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff0030e4e80400000000
        001a0104952615780a0bb5a35955a027
        0c505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101012e3680a070381f403020
        35007ed71000001a0000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000fe004c
        4720446973706c61790a2020000000fe
        004c503137335746342d53504635004c
    GAMMA_LUT_SIZE: 4096 
        range: (0, -1)
    DEGAMMA_LUT_SIZE: 4096 
        range: (0, -1)
    GAMMA_LUT: 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    CTM: 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
        0 1 
    DEGAMMA_LUT: 0 
        range: (0, 65535)
    TearFree: auto 
        supported: off, on, auto
    vrr_capable: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
    max bpc: 8 
        range: (8, 16)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: off, on, auto
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 59 
        supported: 59
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1920x1080 (0x59) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1680x1050 (0x5a) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x1024 (0x5b) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1440x900 (0x5c) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1440 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height  900 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x800 (0x5d) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height  800 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x720 (0x5e) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height  720 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  1024x768 (0x5f) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height  768 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  800x600 (0x60) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   800 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height  600 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
  640x480 (0x61) 138.700MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  66.68KHz
        v: height  480 start 1083 end 1088 total 1111           clock  60.02Hz
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I've no idea where I can try looking in order to resolve this. I've tried enabling variable refresh in the xorg config file using this:

```
Section "Device"
     Identifier "AMD"
     Driver "amdgpu"
     Option "VariableRefresh" "true"
EndSection
```

I'm using a laptop (Asus ROG GL702zc) that does support Freesync between 40 and 60 Hz so I'm not sure why that isn't enabling vrr.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I found out it was Redshift causing the hitching! As soon as I quit it, the hitching stopped happening!

I had it set to autorun with the Xfce session.

---

Old Answer:

It seems that setting Xfwm4's `vblank_mode` Xfconf setting to `off` and turning compositing on seems to fix this. After doing this, I can't see the "hitches" anymore (or they've far more subtle?).

To test this, you can run `xfwm4 --replace --vblank=off &` to respawn xfwm4 with `vblank_mode` set to `off`. To make this change permanent, run `xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode -t string -s "off" --create`.

The only problem with this though is that it causes screen tearing, which isn't ideal. It turns off Vsync :(